# requestAnimationFrame scope change to window

Tags: javascript, requestanimationframe

I have a chain of objects that looks like this:

```
Game.world.update()
```

I would like to use requestAnimationFrame to determine the framerate of this function.

However when I implement it like this:

```
World.prototype.update = function()
{
    requestAnimationFrame(this.update);
}
```

The scope changes from the world object to the window object. **How do I maintain the scope I want while calling requestAnimationFrame()?** I know it has something to do with anonymous functions and such, but I can't get my head around it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Usual approach, works everywhere:

```
World.prototype.update = function()
{
    var self = this;
    requestAnimationFrame(function(){self.update()});
}
```

Or with ES5 [`Function.prototype.bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) ([compatibility](http://kangax.github.io/es5-compat-table/#Function.prototype.bind%5d)):

```
World.prototype.update = function()
{
    requestAnimationFrame(this.update.bind(this)});
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way of doing this is to use a lambda expression like so:

`requestAnimationFrame((timestamp) => { loop(timestamp) });`

This also maintains scope but it's a bit cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

```
Game.world.update.call(scope);
```

Where scope is whatever scope you want to pass in.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call#Description

Comment: requestAnimationFrame(this.update.call(this));

I tried this, but then I get problems with the stack...